# Событие клика на ссылку

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. 
При клике на ссылку появляются пункты меню, и если после этого кликнуть в любое место экрана (кроме ссылки которая активирует меню) - меню пропадает.

Каким образом сделать чтоб меню пропадало еще и при повторном клике на эту же ссылку?

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
  padding: 3px;
}
.menu a {
  display: block;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.active_menu {
  display: block;
}
.active_menu:focus ~ .menu,
.active_menu:active ~ .menu,
.menu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class='active_menu' href='javascript:void(0)' tabindex='1' href="#menu">Развернуть меню</a>

<div class="menu">
  <a href="/">Главная</a>  <a href="/">Весь каталог</a>  <a href="/">Досавка</a>  <a href="/">Оплата</a>  <a href="/">Условия</a>
</div>
```

Comment: У Вас действо завязано на фокусе элемента. Кликнув по нему, произойдёт опять фокус, вот и не работает. Поменяйте метод открытия (скрытый `checkbox`?) и жизнь наладится.

Comment: @Other не совсем понимаю где его менять. не могли бы вы написать решение в ответ. Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.active_menu input:checked + .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class='active_menu' style='cursor: pointer'>
  <input id='checkbox' type='checkbox'  style='display: none'>
  Развернуть меню
  
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="/">Главная</a>
    <a href="/">Весь каталог</a>
    <a href="/">Досавка</a>
    <a href="/">Оплата</a>
    <a href="/">Условия</a>
  </div>

</label>
```

Comment: А клик по сторонам не приводит к закрытию.

Comment: @Other, есть предложения?

Comment: @Doofy, сделать чекбокс 1000 на 1000 чтобы покрывал всю страницу :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, а для тех, у кого рабочая область поболе будет?

Comment: @Doofy, в каждой шутке есть доля шутки :) можно сделать чекбоксу не `display: none`, а `opacity: 0;` и `position: absolute` и ширину и высоту 100% :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, Тогда оно и открываться будет с любого места :D

Comment: @Doofy, данный функционал можно отнести к фичам, а не к багам :)

Comment: Моё предложение таково: предложенная концепция нуждается в переработке ради удовлетворения всем требованиям. Сейчас, без особых шаманств, сделать это нельзя.

Comment: @Other, на ум ничего не приходит сделать это без вмешательств js

Comment: Угу. К Вашему коду добавить лишь слушатель клика на странице и перевода чекбокса в неактивное состояние.

Comment: @Other, или к коду автора `blur()`

Comment: Хм, а если нужно **Tab**'ом перейти в поле поиска например без сокрытия меню?

Comment: @Other, даже не знаю надо ли это. Если юзер идёт к поиску, список меню ему уже не нужен

Comment: Всё упирается в то, что мы не знаем контекста применения. В некоторых случаях это удобно ИМХО.

Answer (score 2):

Его можно сделать еще с помощью плагина `jQuery` таким способом:

```
<script>
 $('#menu').hide();
 $('#Razvernut').on('click', function(){
 $('#menu').show();
 });
</script>

<a class='active_menu' id="Razvernut" href='javascript:void(0)' tabindex='1' href="#menu">Развернуть меню</a> <!--Добавил к тэгу ID="menu"-->

<div class="menu" id="menu"> <!--Добавил к тэгу ID="menu"-->
  <a href="/">Главная</a>  
  <a href="/">Весь каталог</a>  
  <a href="/">Доставка</a>  
  <a href="/">Оплата</a>  
  <a href="/">Условия</a>
</div>
```

А если ты хочешь сделать на `CSS`, то сделай с помощью `chekbox` так:

```css
.menu,
#menyu {
  display: none;
}
.NajmiMenya {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
#menyu:checked ~ .menu {
  display: block;
}
.ubrattocki {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="menyu" type="checkbox" />
<label for="menyu" class="NajmiMenya">Развернуть Меню</label>
<ul class="menu ubrattocki">
  <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Весь каталог</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Доставка</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Оплата</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Условия</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Жить не можете без jquery

Comment: Я поправил) С помощью css тож написал...